# Possible bug in Solve function?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.3 or later**

---

In `11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)` writing:

```
f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := w*x^2*y^3 - z*(w^2 + x^2 + y^2 - 1)

eqn = {D[f[w, x, y, z], w] == 0, 
       D[f[w, x, y, z], x] == 0, 
       D[f[w, x, y, z], y] == 0, 
       D[f[w, x, y, z], z] == 0};

sol = Solve[eqn];

Table[eqn /. sol[[n]], {n, Length[sol]}]
```

I get:

> {{True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {False, True, True, False}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {False, True, True, False}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {False, True, True, False}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {False, True, True, False}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}, 
>     {True, True, True, True}}

from which there are four wrong solutions.

Am I wrong or is it a `Solve[]` bug?

---

**EDIT**: through the email address *support@wolfram.com* I contacted *Wolfram Technical Support* who in less than three working days have confirmed that it is a bug and have already proceeded to report to their developers.

Comment: You could use `List@ToRules@Reduce[eqn, {x, y, z, w}]` to get all valid solutions. Filter for those that only have numeric values on the RHS of `->`.

Comment: `Select[sol, And @@ eqn /. # &]`

Comment: Next time, please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag yourself on a question. The tag is only supposed to be added after your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: In version `12.0` bug is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for asking! In version 9.0 only 16 solutions are returned and they are all valid. In version 10.2 there are 20 solutions, with the extra 4 all being invalid. Contragulations! I think you found a bug. You may want to click "Help", then "Give Feedback...", and then fill out the form in your browser to report.

As another answer notes, you can always try `Reduce[]` instead which **may** give better results in some cases, but `Solve[]` is usually what you want.

Comment: @TeM You *should* report it to Wolfram first, otherwise there's no chance for it to get fixed.

Comment: @TeM http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Reduce`

```
f[w_, x_, y_, z_] := w*x^2*y^3 - z*(w^2 + x^2 + y^2 - 1)
eqn = {D[f[w, x, y, z], w] == 0, D[f[w, x, y, z], x] == 0, 
   D[f[w, x, y, z], y] == 0, D[f[w, x, y, z], z] == 0};
red = Reduce[eqn, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> $\left(z=0\land x=0\land w=-\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)\lor \left(z=0\land x=0\land w=\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)\lor \left(z=0\land y=0\land
>    w=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\lor \left(z=0\land y=0\land w=\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\lor (z=0\land y=-1\land x=0\land w=0)\lor (z=0\land y=0\land x=0\land
>    w=-1)\lor (z=0\land y=0\land x=0\land w=1)\lor (z=0\land y=1\land x=0\land w=0)\lor \left(z=-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land
>    x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\lor \left(z=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land
>    w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)\\
> \lor \left(z=\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\land y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\land w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)$

```
First@eqn //. {ToRules[red]}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True}

Comment: I believe `Solve` use  the function `Reduce` under the hood. when you remove `Backsubstitution -> True`, you'll find implicit solution, somehow `Solve` messes up somewhere and it is definitely a bug..